# Display order of imshow window

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, imshow

[image]In my application i have GUI window, which is displaying always. 
When i launch cv2.imshow, it will display under my GUI window. Is it possible to enforce displaying cv2.imshow window as first?

Best regards,
Adam

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem statement? *it will display under my GUI window* what does it mean? An image will help

Comment: "imshow" is intended mostly for debugging purposes. Use tkinter for displaying your images

Comment: @JeruLuke i added image... i hope it helps you understanding my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put `cv2.namedWindow("window_name")`
 when you want it to show up (say, first command of `main`). Later, you can use `cv2.imshow("window_name",img)` to display the picture.

Comment: Ehh, I added the picture above. I run a function in the GUI, which opens the image in the window (imshow). Unfortunately, the window is open behind the main window GUI.